Set padding of HTML element based on width of preceding element
I am formatting a Shakespearean script in HTML. Because Shakespeare wrote in meter, it is customary to indent lines that do not begin on the first beat of the meter, like so:
p.indent { padding-left: 100pt; }


<h4>HERMIA</h4>
<p>O me!</p>
<h5>[To Helena]</h5>
<p class="indent">You juggler, you cankerblossom,</p>
<p>You thief of love! What, have you come by night</p>
<p>And stol’n my love’s heart from him?</p>
<h4>HELENA</h4>
<p class="indent">Fine, i’ faith.</p>
<p>Have you no modesty, no maiden shame,</p>
<p>No touch of bashfulness? What, will you tear</p>
<p>Impatient answers from my gentle tongue?</p>
<p>Fie, fie, you counterfeit, you puppet, you!</p>
<h4>HERMIA</h4>
<p>“Puppet”? Why so? Ay, that way goes the game.</p>
<p>Now I perceive that she hath made compare</p>


HERMIA
O me!
[To Helena]
        You juggler, you cankerblossom,
You thief of love! What, have you come by night
And stol’n my love’s heart from him?
HELENA
        Fine, i’ faith.
Have you no modesty, no maiden shame,
No touch of bashfulness? What, will you tear
Impatient answers from my gentle tongue?
Fie, fie, you counterfeit, you puppet, you!
HERMIA
“Puppet”? Why so? Ay, that way goes the game.
Now I perceive that she hath made compare

However, rather than indent by a fixed amount, it would be ideal to indent to the width of the prior line. That would produce an appearance closer to this:

HERMIA
O me!
[To Helena]
   You juggler, you cankerblossom,
You thief of love! What, have you come by night
And stol’n my love’s heart from him?
HELENA
                 Fine, i’ faith.
Have you no modesty, no maiden shame,
No touch of bashfulness? What, will you tear
Impatient answers from my gentle tongue?
Fie, fie, you counterfeit, you puppet, you!
HERMIA
“Puppet”? Why so? Ay, that way goes the game.
Now I perceive that she hath made compare

In the desired solution, the amount of left-padding of each p.indent element should bes equal to the width of the most recent prior p element (which in general is not the most recent prior element, as h4 or h5 elements may intervene).
I assume I can't do this in pure CSS, but I've been surprised about that before. If not, then simple JS?

Are you quoting a dialog in MLA?

I really think it would not be a good idea to use my solution.
But just for the challenge of doing it with pure css


p:has(+ h5), p:has(+h4){
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
}
p + h5:has(+ p.indent), p + h4:has(+ p.indent) {
    margin-top: 4em;
    position: absolute;
}
p + h5 + p.indent, p + h4 + p.indent {
    margin-top: 7em;
}
<h4>HERMIA</h4>
<p>O me!</p>
<h5>[To Helena]</h5>
<p class="indent">You juggler, you cankerblossom,</p>
<p>You thief of love! What, have you come by night</p>
<p>And stol’n my love’s heart from him?</p>
<h4>HELENA</h4>
<p class="indent">Fine, i’ faith.</p>
<p>Have you no modesty, no maiden shame,</p>
<p>No touch of bashfulness? What, will you tear</p>
<p>Impatient answers from my gentle tongue?</p>
<p>Fie, fie, you counterfeit, you puppet, you!</p>



Some explanation: I apply a float:left to last p before a paragraph (you may need to add some other cases. For example, in your text, all those "last p" precede a h4 or a h5. But maybe you also have some "last p" preceding directly a p.indent, in which case, you would need to add a rule for that too (p:has(+ p.indent) { margin-bottom: 3em; margin-top: 0; float: left;}, plus a p + p.indent {margin-top: 3em;} for example).
Because the last p is float left, and has a bottom margin big enough, the next element will continue horizontally where it ended. Note that that margin-bottom has to take into account the intermediate h4 or h5 (hence the reason why, in previous paragraph, my new rule for potential case p+p.indent doesn't use the same margin-bottom as in case p+h4/h5+p.indent).
But, that comes with another consequence : it is not part of normal flow. So, I need also to add a margin-top to next element to compensate.
And that is made more complicated by the fact that after that "last p" could be a h4 or h5 (that is even, as I said, the only case I've convered in that short snippet). But I don't want h4 or h5 to be indented. So to avoid that h4/h5 to be impacted by the float:left consequence, I put them in position:absolute. But then, their height neither isn't counted in the flow, hence an even bigger top-margin for next element.
Lastly, a more minor, but still visible consequence, of the float:left of some p, is that those p cannot do margin fusion with their predecessors (because they are not in the same flow). Hence the margin-top:0 for those float:left
So, more a "challenge accepted" answer than a real answer. I wouldn't really do that if it was for me. Besides, I like JS for this kind of usage. And here the needed adaptation each times you add a new case that wasn't coded is too heavy. For example, what if you have some p+h4+h5+p.indent case (easy, just another rule to add for that case. But when is it too much rules?)
More complete rules
including those that I added in the text, so covering more combinations of p, p.indent, h4, h5.
So it proves on one hand that it is possible to add more and more rules to make it work for any possibility.
But it also proves that using this probably doom you to have, from times to times, to add rules each times you encounter a new combination of [p|p.indent|h4|h5]* sequence.


p:has(+ h5), p:has(+h4){
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
}
p + h5:has(+ p.indent), p + h4:has(+ p.indent) {
    margin-top: 4em;
    position: absolute;
}
p + h5 + p.indent, p + h4 + p.indent {
    margin-top: 7em;
}

p:has(+ p.indent) {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
}

p + p.indent {
    margin-top: 3em;
}

p:has(+h4+h5){
    margin-bottom:7em;
}

p + h4:has(+h5+p.indent) {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 4em;
}

p + h4 + h5:has(+p.indent){
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 7em;
}

p + h4 + h5 + p.indent {
    margin-top: 9em;
}
<h4>HERMIA</h4>
<p>O me!</p>
<h5>[To Helena]</h5>
<p class="indent">You juggler, you cankerblossom,</p>
<p>You thief of love! What, have you come by night</p>
<p>And stol’n my love’s heart from him?</p>
<h4>HELENA</h4>
<p class="indent">Fine, i’ faith.</p>
<p>Have you no modesty, no maiden shame,</p>
<p>No touch of bashfulness? What, will you tear</p>
<p>Impatient answers from my gentle tongue?</p>
<p>Fie, fie, you counterfeit, you puppet, you!</p>
<p class=indent> Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem and stuff</p>
<h4>WHOEVER</h4>
<h5>[To Someone else]</h5>
<p class=indent>Yet another remark</p>
<p>Do not really use this CSS only method</p>




Wow, this is amazing with a just tad to much crazy sprinkled on top, Props to you!

This would work for actually printing it out then too, right?

@sheriffderek Well, apparently, yes. I didn't think about that before (I must confess, I never took the time to understand what differentiate a print from a screen, rendering-wise). So, I can only base my answer to "does it work for printing" on the fact that, on my browser, it does.

I guess the JS version would, too, though - now that I'm thinking about it. / since it's rendered - and THEN you print it. Very cool use though! : )

This is precisely why I wrote "I assume I can't do this in pure CSS, but I've been surprised about that before" rather than just assuming I was asking a JS question straight away. Amazing, I laughed aloud, +1. However, I am ultimately heeding your many admonishments to not actually use this answer. If for no other reason, I'd like to add some top and bottom margin to the styling of the h4 and h5 elements, and I don't feel like constantly redoing the math to figure out how tall the various p combos need to be every time I adjust that.

I doubt this is achievable with css alone.
Javascript to determine indents
It's fairly straight forward to apply an indent. IE setting a padding-left value.
(though this does not play nicely with line-breaks inside of <p> tags, if line-breaks are expected, you would prepend the line with the required amount of &nbsp;s to apply the offset)
To find the amount to pad, we need to know what the pairs of <p> tags are.  Once we have all pairs collected we can figure out the position of last character and use that to indent the next line. (in case of line-breaks inside <p> you might need the translate that position to an increment of &nbsp;s)


function getLastCharacterCoordinates(element) {
  const textNode = element.firstChild;
  const textLength = textNode.length;
  if (textLength === 0) return null;

  const range = document.createRange();
  // Set the range to select only the last character
  range.setStart(textNode, textLength - 1);
  range.setEnd(textNode, textLength);
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: rect.left,
    y: rect.top
  };
}

function setIndent(element, indentSize) {
  // you might need to prepend &nbsp; characters instead of setting paddingLeft. depends on whether there are line-breaks inside your p tags. 
  element.style.paddingLeft = `${indentSize}px`
}

function findPairs() {
  // returns an array of pairing <p> tags, 
  // where the next line should start at the end of the previous line.
  const boundary = document.getElementById("boundary");
  const children = Array.from(boundary.children);
  // Reduce to find pairs of <p> tags separated by any other tag
  const result = children.reduce((acc, child, index, arr) => {
    // If the current element is <p> and there is a next element
    if (child.tagName === 'P' && index < arr.length - 2) {
      const nextTag = arr[index + 1].tagName; // Check the tag in between
      const nextP = arr[index + 2]; // The tag two steps ahead
      // If the element two steps ahead is also a <p> and there is another tag in between
      if (nextP.tagName === 'P' && nextTag !== 'P') {
        // we found a pair
        acc.push([child, nextP]);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return result;
}

// call the functions and apply the indents:
const pairs = findPairs()
pairs.forEach(pair => {
  const cord = getLastCharacterCoordinates(pair[0])
  setIndent(pair[1], cord.x)
})
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  /* remove default browser margins */
  margin: 0;
}
<div id="boundary">
  <h4>HERMIA</h4>
  <p>O me!</p>
  <h5>[To Helena]</h5>
  <p>You juggler, you cankerblossom,</p>
  <p>You thief of love! What, have you come by night</p>
  <p>And stol’n my love’s heart from him?</p>
  <h4>HELENA</h4>
  <p>Fine, i’ faith.</p>
  <p>Have you no modesty, no maiden shame,</p>
  <p>No touch of bashfulness? What, will you tear</p>
  <p>Impatient answers from my gentle tongue?</p>
  <p>Fie, fie, you counterfeit, you puppet, you!</p>
</div>




Thanks! This was a very helpful launchpad for me to write my own solution (see my answer below). The approach of using reduce over the full list of elements on the page was a key insight. I was able to simplify a lot from yours because (1) I wasn't worried about multiple lines in a paragraph, (2) I was willing to alter the structure of my document's markup to make this task more convenient to do, and (3) I wasn't trying to automate the identification of where indents are needed. (You seemingly used logic of "whenever exactly 1 non-p tag intercedes between 2 ps, which is not correct.)

At first, I thought I could just read the length of the words in the heading / but that's not really the same if it's uppercase or lowercase, and it isn't a winning approach.
Are you sure you want to hand put those '.indent' classes? What about just anything after a heading? The first paragraph after any heading? Either way the tools you'd use would be the same.
For each .indent paragraph, identify the nearest preceding sibling that is a heading ( to )  You can use .previousSibling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling -- then to get the width of the actual font/text in the heading - you kinda need a span or some sub element that isn't a block-level element (not full-width) / so, you can either put that in there when rendered - or add it with JS. Then you can check those with getBoundingClientRect() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect -- and then you can check that width and use that to set the indent of it's sibling paragraph. I think that's about as simple as you're going to get. Alternatively, you could grab all the elements, and go down and use nextSibling and get the first paragraph after headings.

I wanted to just help you get to a place where you could try it, but if you want a code example https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/JoPXxeX/b987a483fabcd068f441ed3e4fffed99?editors=1011

You've misunderstood the assignment, unfortunately. The position of "You juggler, you cankerblossom" should be determined by the width of "O me!", not "[To Helena]". Likewise the position of "Fine, i' faith" should be determined by the width of "And stol’n my love’s heart from him?", not "HELENA". The idea is to convey that e.g. "And stol’n my love’s heart from him? Fine, i’ faith" is a single line of iambic pentameter—even though the speaker changes midway through—by positioning the second speaker's words in the same horizontal position on the page as if they had been part of a single line.

Yeah. I can't really understand you thing. : )

I ultimately wrote an extremely simple js implementation heavily inspired by Lars' answer.
First, as Lars pointed out, my existing markup is inconvenient for this task because I am interested in measuring the length of the text of certain lines, but each line of text is only enclosed in p tags which are block-level. So I first changed my markup to enclose each line in a span, and apply the indent to the span rather than to the paragraph:
<p><span class="line indent">You juggler, you cankerblossom,</span></p>
<p><span class="line">You thief of love! What, have you come by night</span></p>

Then I wrote a simple javascript function to go through every line on the page, and if it has the indent class, update its left padding to equal to the width of the prior line.
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("line")).reduce(
    (prior, current) => {
        if (current.classList.contains("indent")) {
            current.style.paddingLeft = prior.offsetWidth + "px";
        }; 
        return current;
    }
);

I'm kind of abusing the first parameter of reduce here as a way to get the previous line without having to access it by its index, but since I only care about the side effects and not the ultimate return value, it works out OK.
